# Access crystal report's print button programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

can we access crystal report's  print button programmatically. Is that button is a property or an event?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print crystal report you may convert it to pdf then user may print it from pdf

```
rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "ExportedReport");
```

You also have print to printer and printeroption available

```
rpt.PrintToPrinter(2, true, 1, 2);
```

You may also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227723%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) tutorial

Fror Print Dialog you may see [this](http://aspalliance.com/509_Automatically_Printing_Crystal_Reports_in_ASPNET.3) and [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?537279-How-to-Directly-Print-a-Crystal-Reports-to-Default-Client-Printer-from-ASP-NET-withou) tutorial

Comment: we already done this...   we want the print without showing the pdf. And we also want the print dialogue box. is it possible to open the print dialogue from a button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can print crystal report directly without open it using **CrystalReport.PrintToPrinter()**
Method.

also you can set paper size using **CrystalReport.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperA4.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way ...

```
ReportDocument oDocument = new ReportDocument();
oDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "//ReportPath//ReportName.rpt");
oDocument.SetDataSource(new DataSet()); // Added report data as dataset.

crviewer.ReportSource = oDocument;
crviewer.PrintReport();
```